# C# access string value from class inside another class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to access a `string` that's in a `Class` accessed through another `Class`, from a third `Class`.

In this case the `SelectedCar` is the **SelectedItem** in a `ListView`
& 
and the `SelectedModel` is the **SelectedItem** in a `ListView`

**Car**

```
public class Car : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    private ObservableCollection<CarModel> _models;

    public Car()
    {

    }
    public Car(string name, ObservableCollection<CarModel> models)
    {
        Name = name;
        Models = models;
    }

    public Car(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public static Car Create(string name, ObservableCollection<CarModel> models)
        => new Car(name, models);

    public static Car Create(string name)
        => new Car(name);

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CarModel> Models
    {
        get => _models;
        set => SetProperty(ref _models, value);
    }
}
```

**CarViewModel**

```
  public class CarViewModel : ViewModelBase, ICarViewModel
{
    private string _enteredModel;
    private string _enteredCar;

    private Car _selectedCar;
    private CarModel _selectedModel;

    private ObservableCollection<CarModel> _carModels;
    private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars;

    [DesignOnly(true)]
    public CarViewModel()
    {
        Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>
        {
            Car.Create("Audi",
                new ObservableCollection<CarModel>()
                {
                    CarModel.Create("A1"),
                    CarModel.Create("A2"),
                    CarModel.Create("A3"),
                    CarModel.Create("A4"),
                    CarModel.Create("A5")
                }),

            Car.Create("Mercedes",
                new ObservableCollection<CarModel>()
                {
                    CarModel.Create("A-Class"),
                    CarModel.Create("B-Class"),
                    CarModel.Create("C-Class"),
                    CarModel.Create("E-Class"),
                    CarModel.Create("S-Class")
                }),

            Car.Create("BMW",
                new ObservableCollection<CarModel>()
                {
                    CarModel.Create("1-Serie"),
                    CarModel.Create("2-Serie"),
                    CarModel.Create("3-Serie"),
                    CarModel.Create("4-Serie"),
                    CarModel.Create("5-Serie")
                }),

            Car.Create("Volkswagen",
                new ObservableCollection<CarModel>()
                {
                    CarModel.Create("Golf"),
                    CarModel.Create("Passat"),
                    CarModel.Create("Arteon"),
                    CarModel.Create("T-Cross"),
                    CarModel.Create("Up!")
                }),

            Car.Create("Volvo",
                new ObservableCollection<CarModel>()
                {
                    CarModel.Create("V60"),
                    CarModel.Create("V70"),
                    CarModel.Create("XC60"),
                    CarModel.Create("XC90"),
                    CarModel.Create("S90")
                }),
        };

        DeleteModelCommand = new DelegateCommand(DeleteModelExecuted, DeleteModelCanExecute);
        DeleteCarCommand = new DelegateCommand(DeleteCarExecuted, DeleteCarCanExecute);

        AddCarCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddCarExecuted, AddCarCanExecute);
        AddModelCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddModelExecuted, AddModelCanExecute);
    }

    public string EnteredModel
    {
        get => _enteredModel;
        set => SetProperty(ref _enteredModel, value);
    }

    public string EnteredCar
    {
        get => _enteredCar;
        set => SetProperty(ref _enteredCar, value);
    }

    public Car SelectedCar
    {
        get => _selectedCar;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedCar, value);
    }

    public CarModel SelectedModel
    {
        get => _selectedModel;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedModel, value);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
    {
        get => _cars;
        set => SetProperty(ref _cars, value);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CarModel> CarModels
    {
        get => _carModels;
        set => SetProperty(ref _carModels, value);
    }
}
```

**CarModifierViewModel**

```
 public class CarModifierViewModel : ViewModelBase, ICarModifierViewModel
{
    private CarColorModel _selectedColor;
    private CarModifierModel _selectedYear;

    private string _previouslySelectedCar;
    private string _previouslySelectedModel;

    private ObservableCollection<CarModifierModel> _modifierModels;

    private CarViewModel _carViewModelClass;

    [DesignOnly(true)]
    public CarModifierViewModel()
    {
        ModifierModels = new ObservableCollection<CarModifierModel>
        {
           CarModifierModel.Create(2000, new ObservableCollection<CarColorModel>()
           {
               CarColorModel.Create("Silver"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Black")
           }),
           CarModifierModel.Create(2005, new ObservableCollection<CarColorModel>()
           {
               CarColorModel.Create("Silver"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Black"),
               CarColorModel.Create("White")
           }),
           CarModifierModel.Create(2010, new ObservableCollection<CarColorModel>()
           {
               CarColorModel.Create("Silver"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Black"),
               CarColorModel.Create("White"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Blue")
           }),
           CarModifierModel.Create(2015, new ObservableCollection<CarColorModel>()
           {
               CarColorModel.Create("Silver"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Black"),
               CarColorModel.Create("White"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Blue"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Red")
           }),
           CarModifierModel.Create(2020, new ObservableCollection<CarColorModel>()
           {
               CarColorModel.Create("Silver"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Black"),
               CarColorModel.Create("White"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Blue"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Red"),
               CarColorModel.Create("Purple")
           })
        };
    }

    public CarColorModel SelectedColor
    {
        get => _selectedColor;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedColor, value);
    }

    public CarModifierModel SelectedYear
    {
        get => _selectedYear;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedYear, value);
            LoadCarAndModel();
        }
    }

    public string PreviouslySelectedCar
    {
        get => _previouslySelectedCar;
        set => SetProperty(ref _previouslySelectedCar, value);
    }

    public string PreviouslySelectedModel
    {
        get => _previouslySelectedModel;
        set => SetProperty(ref _previouslySelectedModel, value);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CarModifierModel> ModifierModels
    {
        get => _modifierModels;
        set => SetProperty(ref _modifierModels, value);
    }

    public CarViewModel CarViewModelClass
    {
        get => _carViewModelClass;
        set => SetProperty(ref _carViewModelClass, value);
    }

    public void LoadCarAndModel()
    {
        CarViewModelClass = new CarViewModel();
        CarViewModelClass.SelectedCar = new Car();
        CarViewModelClass.SelectedCar.Name = new string(CarViewModelClass.SelectedCar.Name);

        PreviouslySelectedCar = CarViewModelClass?.SelectedCar?.Name;
        PreviouslySelectedModel = CarViewModelClass.SelectedModel.Name;

    }
}
```

I hope I did not miss anything crucial, but how do I access the **SelectedItem** from another view? In `CarModifierViewModel` I tried instantiating the class to access but it does not load the **SelectedItem**..

Comment: You have to use composition. Your question is quite confusing at a quick glance. So it's not easy to give you a specific solution e.g., the relationship of the composed classes. Please clarify which class is modifying what class?

Comment: The screenshots, to me, are quite confusing. Please describe in a concise manner, what the problem is and what you're trying to achieve as well as including any supporting code.

Comment: @BionicCode
I'll look up composition. 
Car.cs has a `string Name` , that is being set in CarViewModel.cs. I want to access that from CarModifierViewModel.cs.

Comment: @ColinM The screenshots of the application is to show the `selectedItem` binding that i want to access. 
I am trying to access the selected Car & selected Model in the second view. Which has CarModifierViewModel as it's datacontext. The first view has datacontext CarViewModel

Comment: As a note: UI or an image of it doesn't help to understand or explain any implementation details like class relations. _" Car.cs has a string Name , that is being set in CarViewModel.cs. I want to access that from CarModifierViewModel.cs"_. But you are already accessing this property in the `CarModifierViewModel.LoadCarAndModel()` method using the`CarViewModelClass` property.

Comment: It might be more useful to post a concise implementation of the view instead of a screenshot. This way it is possible to know the actual `DataContext` of each view and how you set them up.

Comment: In `CarModifierViewModel.LoadCarAndModel()` I only get access to the `ObservableCollection<Car>Cars` . I do however not get access to the `SelectedCar` or `SelectedModel` ?

Comment: @BionicCode I try to make my questions shorter, but I never manage too.. Because I am not sure what code to implement in my question.

Comment: I can read something like: `PreviouslySelectedCar = CarViewModelClass?.SelectedCar?.Name;` This is exactly what you are asking about, ain't you?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to get access too. But the SelectedCar & Name are both `null` . Meanwhile CarViewModelClass contains a list of 5 created cars, seen in `CarViewModel` . As you also see i create a `New CarVIewModel();` and a `New Car(); ` But `Car` still contains `null`

Comment: Alright, I see. Since I don't know your exact view design I will show you how to compose view models using a generic example. You should be able to apply it easily to your project.

Comment: I can upload the Xaml code if you want it?

Comment: It's not necessary, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use composition. You usually create a `MainViewModel` which has properties to expose all other view models to the views. The `MainViewModel` injects the required classes into the related view models using a constructor.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
class MainViewModel
{
  public CarViewModel CarViewModel { get; set; }
  public CarModifierViewModel CarModifierViewModel { get; set; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.CarViewModel = new CarViewModel();
    this.CarModifierViewModel = new CarModifierViewModel(this.CarViewModel);
  }
}
```

**CarViewModel.cs**

```
public class CarViewModel
{
  ...
}
```

**CarModifierViewModel.cs**

```
public class CarModifierViewModel
{
  private CarViewModel CarViewModel { get; set; }

  public CarModifierViewModel(CarViewModel carViewModel)
  {
    this.CarViewModel = carViewModel;
  }

  public void LoadCarAndModel()
  {
    // Now 'CarViewModel' won't be null, 
    // as long as you don't pass null to the constructor
    // or set the 'MainViewModel.CarViewModel' property to null
    PreviouslySelectedCar = this.CarViewModel.SelectedCar.Name;
    PreviouslySelectedModel = this.CarViewModel.SelectedModel.Name;
  }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**View1.xaml**

```
<UserControl DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel.CarViewModel}" />
```

**View2.xaml**

```
<UserControl DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel.CarModifierViewModel}" />
```

Comment: I tried this. But apparently it is correct saying I did not provide enough information. I dont actually use the MainWindow/ MainViewModel. I only have a `TabControl` inside the MainWindow. Everything else is through `CarViewModel` and `CarModifierViewModel` . Then i use a `ViewModelLocator` to set the `DataContext` for the different View.

Comment: Yes indeed, you didn't provide much valuable information. but in this case it doesn't matter as long as you are able to extract the knowledge and transfer it to your project. The point is not the way you assign those view model. It is about structuring. Class design. You have to pass a _reference to the actual instance_ to your view model in order to share instance data. Composition is one solution do achieve this. Making the relevant properties `static` could be another but not recommended solution.

Comment: All you have to do is pass a shared instance of `CarViewModel` to `CarModifierViewModel`. It must be the same `CarViewModel` that the other view is working on. So that when a view references `CarModifierViewModel` it has the right shared instance of `CarViewModel` to retrieve the right data. If it's still not clear, no problem. Then please post a shortened version of your locator. I will modify it to make it work.